# Unity performance reporting on iOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

OS : macOS(high sierra) / Unity : 2017.3.1.f1

Hello, I'm processing unity 'performance reporting'.

On Android, work well.
On macOS, work well.
but on iOS, nothing happen.

I did below 
(just followed Unity Documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityPerformanceReportingSymbols.html?_ga=2.140411701.744493884.1523240923-1985243764.1495603759)

1. Turn on 'PERFORMANCE REPORTING' switch on Services tab on Unity Editor
2. Make Error code and Build the application.(for iOS the application built from Xcode)
3. Run application on each platform(Android, macOS, iOS)
4. Check Unity Dash board.

Can checked REPORT from Android and macOS.
but never find the REPORT from iOS.

Could anyone helping me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IOS has a Privacy setting Analysis/Share with App Developers, maybe Unity honors that?

Comment: Have you tried a different iOS version or un update? Unity has system symbol coverage on about 80% of iOS versions, starting from the iOS 7 family. Sometimes Unity doesn't have the right symbol files for every version.

Comment: @eckes thanks for your comment. that issue is relative with 'missing symbols'. if I don't have any privacy permission, performance reporting will show log that hidden privacy information. But my issue was nothing happen.

Comment: @MyIsaak thanks for you comment. I've read the document about coverage. and I've tried test on different iPhone devices. but nothing happened. today I found the log. I don't know why. I guess iOS need more log process time.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I found the solution. On Android and macOS, the log was shown after just a few second on the Unity dash board. However, on iOS, it needs more time.

If someone has the same problem, just wait a bit longer.